# Processing a large image text file

Tags: c++, performance, text-files

I'm using C++ and have a 1234 by 1234 text file with values 0 to 255. I have been trying to speed up my code because its used in real time with the user. Right now it takes .5 seconds to run with .4 seconds devoted to reading the text file to a `vector<vector<int>>`. I am using `getline` then `istringstream`. Below is the code I'm currently using. There is some stuff in there where I get rid of the first and last 50 columns as well as take the first chunk of rows into one vector and the second chunk into another vector because that's how I need it for processing purposes.

```
void readInRawData(string fileName, int start, int split, int finish, vector< vector <int> > &rawArrayTop, vector< vector <int> > &rawArrayBottom)
{
    string line;
    vector<int> rawRow;
    int counter=0;
    int value=0;
    int numberOfColumns=0, numberOfRows=0;
    ifstream rawImage;
    rawImage.open(fileName.c_str()); //open file using fileName
    if (rawImage.is_open()&&!is_empty(rawImage)) 
    {
        int length=0;
        getline(rawImage,line);
        istringstream ss(line);
        while(ss>>value)//clump into values between spaces
        {
            length++;
        }
        while(getline(rawImage, line))//get row
        {
            if(counter<start)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        while(getline(rawImage, line))//get row
        {
            if(counter<split)
            {
                rawRow.clear();
                istringstream ss(line);
                for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
                {
                    ss>>value;
                }
                for(int i=0; i<length-100; i++)
                {
                    ss>>value;
                    rawRow.push_back(value);                        
                }
                rawArrayTop.push_back(rawRow);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        while(getline(rawImage, line))//get row
        {
            if(counter<finish)
            {
                rawRow.clear();
                istringstream ss(line);
                for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
                {
                    ss>>value;
                }
                for(int i=0; i<length-100; i++)
                {
                    ss>>value;
                    rawRow.push_back(value);                        
                }
                rawArrayBottom.push_back(rawRow);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        rawImage.close();
    }
    //if it can't be opened throw error
    else
    {
        throw rawArrayTop;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the compiler options (the optimization settings) used to build your application.  If you're running a "debug" or unoptimized build, the numbers you're showing are basically meaningless.

Comment: Since you know the size of all the vectors beforehand, use reserve to reduce memory reallocations.

Comment: I stated that it will reduce memory reallocations.  That is a fact, no guessing involved.

Comment: If performance is important, you are barking up the wrong tree with a text format, you need to go binary.

Comment: Why you do not use the function fread of languaje c?

Comment: If you are able / allowed to convert the file to binary, you could then just open the file, create a memory mapping over it and access your file data directly (and instantly) as if it were memory (say one big array with your values).

Comment: I am receiving this data from a lab view array. I was having them save it as a text file simple because I have never done anything with a binary file/ do not know how to use one.

Comment: Talk to the folks who supply you with the data and see what other formats they might provide - the easiest for you to read is probably PGM (Portable Grey Map) for greyscale or PPM (Portable Pixmap) for colour - both from the NetPBM suite. Failing that, the next simplest is probably BMP. There are libraries to read these - CImg is very powerful and very simple to integrate  for C++ programmers.

Answer (score -1):

To get a real increase in performance, you'll have to rewrite totally.

```
  while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
  {
     if(isdigit(ch))
     {
       sample = sample * 10 + ch - '0';
       onsample = 1;
     }
     else
     {
        if(onsample)
        {
           *out++ = sample;
           sample = 0;
           onsample = 0;
        }
     }

  }
```

Set up out with malloc(width * height). Now it should zip through the file almost as fast as it can read it.

Answer (score -1):

I will not give you the code, but I will suggest how to proceed here:

1. parsing text takes a long time. If real-time is important, pre-process the file to a binary format, since it can be loaded directly with read/write functions. You will need to create a stream in binary mode from the binary file and use istream::read.
2. try to avoid `vector<vector<int>>` unless you use scoped allocators, which I assume you are not using. This is bad for the cache. It is a much better fit to use a vector with n * m reserved space.

If you need bidimensional accesss, you can just code your functions for that:

```
using Matrix = vector<int>;

int & idx(Matrix, size_t row, size_t col);

Matrix mat(m * n);

idx(mat, 2, 3) = 17;
```

Another concern is that you must load into the Matrix. If you want to avoid redundant initialization and at the same time prereserve memory before loading the data, that is not possible with the stl vector, but you can use  [Boost.Container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/container.html), which has an overload for reserve with default_init_t. That will not trigger initialization of elements in the vector.

3. if the values are between 0 and 255 use char, not int. You will fit more data at once in cache.